# How do I select and transform just one layer at a time in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

In Illustrator, I pressed something and everything except one selected layer became greyed out and I could transform the single object that was selected. There was also a back arrow (pointing left) at the top left-hand corner of the art panel that I clicked to get back to normal. How do I get back into this singular layer selection for object editing?

Comment: You were in isolation mode. More info on the Adobe help site here: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/selecting-objects.html

Comment: thank you, that worked